# What kind of term or slang is used by English speakers today as a kind of sigh in verbal form?

Tags: word-request

What I mean is this.

Suppose someone puts you in a situation that annoys you. You want to express your dissatisfaction to the other person.

The first option is rolling your eyes or saying, ironically, stuff like "oh shit!".

Is there some less hardcore, or more funny, that can be used without swearing?

Comment: This is far too open-ended. Rolling your eyes, showing an upturned palm, curling your lip, etc., aren't even *language* - let alone *English*. But before it gets closed, I'll just throw in ***No shit, Sherlock**!* as "more funny" than ***Oh, shit**!* when disparagingly responding to someone's unhelpful ***statement of the bleedin' obvious.***

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that. 

Comment: A sarcastic "Wow" is a current favorite (especially if the dissatisfaction is severe). Or it was; I'm over 40 so I'm automatically out of date with trending slang verbiage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This list [300+ Ways to Say "Sigh"](https://kathysteinemann.com/Musings/sigh/) is for writers who want to show their character sighing.  Maybe you can find some ideas from there, depending on *your reason for sighing*.  There is no ONE replacement; it's good to be more specific anyway.

Several from that list that might work for you:

- "You're impossible !"
- "Aargh!"
- "No, no, no, no, NO!"
- "Humph"

Also, the list shows various ways to ACT OUT your sighing in conjunction with your verbal expression, depending on the motivation:

- *Cynicism*: smirking
- *Exasperation*: shaking your head, puting head in your hands
- *Anger*: gritting your teeth
- etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could just say, "Sigh" in a forlorn way.

It expresses the feeling of a sigh in a rather pointed way, and is a bit humorous.

Comment: I mean, "sigh" is something of an onomatopoeia, so just saying "sigh" is not far off from the actual sound of sighing.

Comment: Reminds me of this great clip from The Simpsons: https://youtu.be/k5kks4_khd4

Answer (score 4):

“Oof” or “woof” might work here.

Otherwise, I think most native speakers would say something ironically, like “gee, thanks” spoken in a dissatisfied tone.

Answer (score 3):

As GratefulDisciple said, there are many.  I would say "[**Sheesh**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sheesh)" is a good one that may take the place of a sigh and an eyeroll.

If they're being annoying, I'm not sure that a sigh would be the reaction I'd expect someone to have, unless they're trying to let go of their annoyance—in which case the sigh itself is kind of necessary, it's a calming action, I can't think of a verbal response which would have the same kind of result.

Can you explain the emotions of the person whose sigh you want to replace with words?  Are they irritated, resigned, etc.?

Comment: Thanks, Derek. I was thinking in terms of annoyance, dissatisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the receiving end of "Rolls eyes out loud !" a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this.

"Ah, here we go again." with an obvious dissatisfactory tone that sometimes can be expressed in a funny way.

It suits your requirement well.

> Is there some less hardcore, or more funny, that can be used without
> swearing?

Answer (score 0):

For the 25 and under crowd-

"Bruh"
"Sheesh"
"For real?"
"Come on, dude"
"Jeez"
"Christ"
"You serious?"

or most combinations of the above, i.e.

Bruh, for real?

Come on dude, you serious?

etc... hundreds of other options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).